# JS code executed after everything else

Tags: jquery

How to make sure a particular jQuery code snippet will be executed after all other jQuery code ?

(the reason I'm asking is because I need to manipulate elements that have been dynamically added by some plugin, and when I try to do it with normal jQuery code it fails. I conclude that the plugin adds the elements AFTER my code was executed)

Comment: Plugins usually provide a callback function that would be called after it completes loading. Check the plugin documentation for such callback function, if not then you may have to modify that plugin to call your function after it finishes it load.